# .trigger("change") not working in .on("change")

Tags: jquery

I used `.on("change")` event function because there's a part in my whole code that changes dynamically. `.trigger("change")` works fine in `.change()` but not on `.on("change")`. Here is my code:

```
    $('#popupContent').on('change', '#gradeYearLevel', function() {
        var $course = $('#course');
        var $section = $('#section');

        if ($(this).val() > 4) {
            $type = 0;
        }
        else {
            $type = 1;
        }
        if ($('#gradeYearLevel').val() == '') {
            $course.empty().append($("<option>", {"value": ""}).html("-- Select --"));
            $section.empty().append($("<option>", {"value": ""}).html("-- Select --"));
        }
        else {
            $.getJSON(BASE_PATH + "getJSONCoursesByType/" + $type, function(data) {
                $course.empty().append($("<option>", {"value": ""}).html("-- Select --"));
                $.each(data, function(k,v){
                    $course.append(
                        $("<option>", {"value": v.id}).html(v.title)
                    );
                });
            });
            $.getJSON(BASE_PATH + "getJSONSectionsByType/" + $type, function(data) {
                $section.empty().append($("<option>", {"value": ""}).html("-- Select --"));
                $.each(data, function(k,v){
                    $section.append(
                        $("<option>", {"value": v.id}).html(v.name)
                    );
                });
            });
        }
    }).trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you're triggering the `change` event on the `#popupContent` element as returned from `on()`, *not* the `#gradeYearLevel` which the delegated event handler is listening for.

You need to call `trigger()` on the child element so that the event can bubble. Try this:

```
$('#popupContent').on('change', '#gradeYearLevel', function() {
    // your code here...
})

$('#gradeYearLevel').trigger("change");
```

Comment: I've also tried that but still no effect. I tested a simple code last time like:
 $('#button1').on('change', function etc.. with .trigger("change"); at last but no effect.

Comment: Does the `#gradeYearLevel` element exist in the DOM when you call `trigger()`?

Comment: Maybe not, why I used the function .on() instead .change().

Comment: `on('change, fn)` and `change()` are the same thing. I can't repro the issue, the code above works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/1uwL3fu8/